# Using array of HTML values to select checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically, I have a bunch of input checkboxes on a page. I am attempting to group many of these checkboxes together. What I am doing is putting another section of checkboxes onto the page, these "group checkboxes" will check all of the existing checkboxes, which I have determined belong to a group. I have code that works for one grouping just fine. My problem is I have to do this about 20 more times and I don't want to repeat this code over and over with the different values. How can I not repeat this code 20 times? Thanks

I think it is possible jQuery inArray() could be helpful. So I have added array of two HTML values called refValues. Any advice?

```
  let refValues = ['mc-ccode:EREF', 'mc-ccode:REF']
  $( "#group-REF" ).change( function () {
    if ( $('.refGroup').is(':checked') ) {
        console.log('checked');
        $('input[value="mc-ccode:EREF"]').prop('checked' , true).prop('disabled' ,true);
        $('input[value="mc-ccode:REF"]').prop('checked' , true).prop('disabled' ,true);
        $('input[value="mc-ccode:REF"]').parent().addClass('cGroup');
        $('input[value="mc-ccode:EREF"]').parent().addClass('cGroup');
      } else {
          console.log('unchecked');
          $('input[value="mc-ccode:EREF"]').prop('checked' , false).prop('disabled' ,false);
          $('input[value="mc-ccode:REF"]').prop('checked' , false).prop('disabled' ,false);
          $('input[value="mc-ccode:REF"]').parent().removeClass('cGroup');
          $('input[value="mc-ccode:EREF"]').parent().removeClass('cGroup');
      }
  })
```

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing the actual HTML.

Comment: use a `class` for each group and then your reusable function can operate with that. Doesn't need jQuery

Comment: How about creating a JS array or object first and write the html dynamically (innerJTML for example) in your form according the values or modify the values accordingly. In your JS Structure you could play with the id of the checkboxes eg. group1_id1  group1_id2 group2_id3 now you can run over your array and split the ides to get according group and id... there are plenty of possibiltys.